Trigger or DataTrigger for complex model in MAUI
In .NET 8 MAUI, I have my custom component that returns an object
public class LanguageModel
{
    public string? LanguageName { get; set; }
    public string? Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string? Flag { get; set; }
    public bool IsSupported { get; set; } = false;
}

Now, I want to add my component in a ContentView and add a Trigger or a DataTrigger to change, for example, the colour of the text. I tried also with a behaviour but it is not working.
For that, I created a simple Converter like this:
public class IsLanguageEmpty : IValueConverter
{
    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, 
        object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is null)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, 
        object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

Now, in the ContentView, I added this XAML
<ldd:LanguageDropdown
    x:Name="lddTarget"
    BorderColor="{StaticResource RedAlert}"
    Placeholder="{lang:Translate DictionaryLanguage}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding LanguageTarget}"
    SemanticProperties.Description="{lang:Translate DictionaryLanguage}"
    TextSize="{StaticResource ElementFontSizeNormal}">
    <ldd:LanguageDropdown.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LanguageTarget, 
                Converter={StaticResource LanguageConverter}}" 
                TargetType="ldd:LanguageDropdown">
            <DataTrigger.Value>true</DataTrigger.Value>
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" 
                Value="{StaticResource RedAlert}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </ldd:LanguageDropdown.Triggers>
</ldd:LanguageDropdown>

The value SelectedValue changes when a new item is selected. If not, it is null or empty. Although the SelectedValue is empty or not, the converter is not called.

Could you please include the relevant code for LanguageDropdown custom control?

You may check if SelectedItem or  BorderColor has been changed using Detect property changes. I cannot reproduce this issue right now (Actually your code works well on my side)
